# Get key names for JSON array for all browser versions

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array and i'd like to get their key names.

I searched and found no solution that really solved the problem. So I created my own:

```
var data = [{ Id: 25 }, {Year: 18} ];

$.each(data, function (i, element) {
    var stringfied = JSON.stringify(element);
    var parts = stringfied.split('":'); //separate key and value
    var key = parts[0].split('{"')[1]; // get key
    console.info(key);
    console.info(element[key]);
});
```

I tried other solutions like:

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.info(key);
    info(data[key]);
}
```

but that didn't show the key names.

Is there a better solution? (Object.keys requires modern browsers, doesn't fit)

Comment: JSON isn't supported (without an external script) in IE7 and below, among other old browsers: http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: the same object used in previous example: var obj = [{ Id: 25 }, {Year: 18} ];

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine what your code will do if one of the keys contains a leading colon.

This will do the job:

```js
var data = [
  {
    Id: 25
  }, 
  {
    Year: 18
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var element = data[i];

  for (var k in element)
    if (element.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      console.log(k);
      console.log(element[k]);
    }
}
```